# Is it realistic for an actor to act in four movies in six months?

Tags: production, realism, acting, once-upon-a-time-in-hollywood

Watching *Once Upon a Time in Hollywood* which, as I understand it, is mostly a pretty realistic portrayal of Hollywood in 1969.

One thing that doesn't feel right, though: the part where the actor is said to have gone off and acted – major roles, at that – four movies in six months. I was under the impression one movie in a year is a more realistic goal.

Am I correct about this part being unrealistic, or am I missing something?

Comment: The film is actually a "comedy-drama" and has a fair amount of satire like most Quintin Tarantino's films...although I would say the satire is more subtle.

Comment: @DarthLocke So which aspects are satire in the sense of being unrealistic?

Comment: In 1978 Jackie Chan acted in 6 movies, 5 of which he was also action coordinator and stunt director for.  In 1986 Bollywood actor Mithun Chakraborty performed in **15** movies.  Lots of Hollywood actors have done more than 4 movies in a year; Christopher Lee starred in 9 movies in 1970.

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, the actors involvement in the making of a movie is quite short and can be quite start-stop rather than a continuous attachment. I recall working on projects where we had to make sure time was well spent with a particular talent as they had to go off and be in another shoot in the same day, and that would not be the only cast member or the only day that it happened. (or we are hanging around waiting for talent to come off another movie..)

Comment: @blobbymcblobby - try working with soap stars in panto season ;)) They all get blocked into a week or so, maybe October, to all 'leave the plot' through various devices, via the train station, taxis, whatever, then these would be staggered into the coming episodes; only to reverse the process after xmas, when they all come trooping back in; having only been 'away' for a week or two, if that, to the public.

Comment: @Tetsujin ahahaha! please, no! Thankfully I have not had to wait for Widow Twankey to turn up to do a sex scene! Yet! Absolutely, the public have absolutely no clue, except when they're sat there with their kids watching said panto... "Maaaam! Isn't that..?"

Comment: @blobbymcblobby - you haven't lived :P [& fortunately, in that respect… neither have I.]

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm keeping a bottle of bleach nearby..

Comment: @blobbymcblobby - hahaha. I recall one year, a movie I was in being about to come out on general release for xmas… but a tube station ad showed someone I knew for certain wasn't in the movie being front & centre in the advert. Took me a minute to figure out they'd not only done the movie, but had also put it on as 'panto' for the season. [No names, no pack drill, but his first name begins with D & his last rhymes with Dyer…  ;) [When I waved him bye bye at the tube station the month before… he hadn't mentioned it, though i did when he trooped back after.]

Comment: @Tetsujin aha! He's normally known by a bunch of other names isn't he? :P Well, he's gotta eat! ;P

Comment: @blobbymcblobby - LOL, yup, but he's actually a really nice, if loud, bloke.

Comment: @Tetsujin that's actually quite nice to hear!

Comment: I wasn't saying that the amount of acting per yr was necessarily the comedy part, just that without looking up info, it *could be since other aspects of the film "poke" fun at the whole era. The in-universe actors themselves are a bit over dramatic as QT approached the whole era with a kind of affectionate mockery. These was just something to consider, not an answer.

Comment: John Wayne did this a lot.

1932 - 9 films
1933 - 11 films
1934 - 9 films
1935 - 8 films
1970 - 5 films

Before WW2 he averaged 6 or 7 films a year, after WW2 it dropped to 2 or 3, with occasional stretches of more.

Comment: *Voice* actors do this all the time.  They can record all the dialogue for an animated film in as little as a day, so they can be far more prolific.  A bit less so these days now that most animated films are using big celebrities for their voices rather than dedicated voice actors, but there's still a lot of this going on.

Comment: Go look at almost any actor's IMDB page. They are often in a lot of stuff you might not have heard of but they are keeping very busy nonetheless

Comment: Yes, you're missing a lot. Four movies in six months might be more than you expected, but where did your expectation come from?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In 1970 [Christopher Lee](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000489) starred in 9 movies, which is actually 1 more than 4 every 6 months.

- [Eugenie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067713)
- [Scream and Scream Again](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064949)
- [The Bloody Judge](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066183)
- [Julius Caesar](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065073)
- [Count Dracula](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065569)
- [Taste the Blood of Dracula](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065922)
- [One More Time](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064727)
- [The Private Life of Sherlock Holmes](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066249)
- [Scars of Dracula](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064494)

This is very close to the era depicted in *One Upon a Time in Hollywood*, so it's certainly an indication that it's not impossible.

In addition, the Bollywood actor [Mithun Chakraborty](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0149822) has **over 370 acting credits** in his 5-decade career, with many years having more than 10 roles.

Comment: FWIW, Eric Roberts has 711 credits. When I tore out everything that wasn't a released film, I found 401 films spanning 45 years. That's an average of 8.7 films per year *on top of* an average of 2.9 TV *shows* (not episodes) per year as well as other credits. All together, that's an average of 12 acting credits per year.

Answer (score 29):

Movie making in 1969 was a lot different to movie making today. Films were made a lot faster and cheaper. It wasn't at all unusual for an actor to star in several films per year.

As a reference point, [Telly Savalas](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001699/?ref_=tt_cl_t_2)  had substantial roles in five films released in 1969.  Not necessarily the protagonist, often the villain, but big roles.

- *The Assassination Bureau*, Lord Boswick, principal vilain.
- *Mackenna's Gold*, Sergeant Tibbs
- *Sophie's Place*, Herbie Haseler, protagonist/ anti-hero
- *Land Raiders*, Vince Carden, top billed.
- *On Her Majesty's Secret Service*, Blofeld, Principal villain.

Comment: Shoot schedules were also a lot shorter, re-shoots less common. These days a 6 week shoot would be normal rather than exceptional. Two weeks would be a late 60s equivalent. 4 would be an expensive movie. Different times;) Actors didn't have to gain 10 kilos for one movie, then lose 10 for the next.

Comment: _"Movie making in 1969 was a lot different to movie making today"_ - I'd have thought with modern movie-making technology (e.g. using 3D CGI instead of building minature models; fixing things in post instead of reshooting; all-digital workflows with instant feedback instead of waiting for dailies to be developed; etc) would have made filmmaking much quicker today compared to the past.

Comment: @Tetsujin: And then you have *Star Wars*, which apparently managed to spend [14½ weeks on interior shots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(film)#Filming), across nine different sound stages, plus another 2½ weeks on-site in Tunisia for the exterior shots.

Comment: @Dai - you'd think so, but as budgets have got bigger, shoot schedules have got longer, with some directors wanting everything from a million angles. The most setups I ever saw for a single scene was 60 - that's 60 different sets of camera positions & lighting with sometimes up to 4 simultaneous cameras & of course multiple takes for each setup. I worked just three scenes on that movie… it took six weeks to shoot them, 6 days a week, 13 hours a day. …and that was *with* instant digital compositing, so we could see roughs of the main CGI character in the scene 'live'.

Answer (score 8):

It may not be clear, but "Once Upon a Time in Hollywood" is actually based on several real people and real events (though with a very different final outcome).

The two lead characters in the movie, Rick Dalton and Cliff Booth are pretty closely based on the actual Burt Reynolds and his long-time stuntman Hal Needham(**).  And if you check [Burt Reynolds filmography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burt_Reynolds_filmography#Film) for 1969, you will find that he did in fact do 4 films in 6 months in 1969: 100 Rifles, Sam Whiskey, Shark! and Impasse.

(** You will find some claims on the internet that they are actually based on Ty Hardin and Gene LeBell, but although there was some partial influence from both of their careers, if you are familiar with all four's history, [Burton and Needham are better fits](https://web.archive.org/web/20190727174410/https://www.esquire.com/entertainment/movies/a28504994/brad-pitt-once-upon-a-time-in-hollywood-character-true-story-stuntman-hal-needham/)).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Movies & TV!  This is very interesting, but the link only tells me that Reynolds did 4 movies in 1969, not that they were in a 6-month span.  Where did you get that detail from?

Comment: @DavidW  Hmm, yep good  point.  It now appears to me that at least 3 of the 4 were *released* in the first half of 1969.  When they were shot is a little less clear.